# Why is getGetFeatureInfoUrl failing?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

Running getGetFeatureInfoUrl() against a TileWms source returns:
Either no layer was queryable, or no layers were specified using QUERY_LAYERS

My URL is:

> https://geoserver.xxx.com/geoserver/yyy/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&format=image%2Fpng&version=1.1.1&layers=yyy%3Aboundaryline&tiled=true&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&I=219&J=208&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-508764.86026613414%2C6966165.009797823%2C-469629.1017841239%2C7005300.768279833

GeoServer docs say:
**If application/vnd.ogc.gml is supported the request should be successful.**
All of the layers in question have GML as an available output format in the layer preview options in GeoServer.

OpenLayers docs say:
**If QUERY_LAYERS is not provided then the layers specified in the LAYERS parameter will be used.**
LAYERS params is set on all these layers upon configuration.

Comment: what is the **exact** url you are trying?

Comment: getFeatureInfoUrl returns

https://geoserver.xxx.com/geoserver/yyy/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&format=image%2Fpng&version=1.1.1&layers=yyy%3Aboundaryline&tiled=true&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&I=219&J=208&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-508764.86026613414%2C6966165.009797823%2C-469629.1017841239%2C7005300.768279833

Comment: Please edit your question with any additional info, don't put it in comments.

Comment: try this --> 


https://geoserver.xxx.com/geoserver/yyy/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&BBOX=-508764.86026613414,6966165.009797823,-469629.1017841239,7005300.768279833&SERVICE=WMS&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&QUERY_LAYERS=yyy:boundaryline&FEATURE_COUNT=50&Layers=yyy:boundaryline&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&format=image/png&styles=&srs=EPSG:3857&version=1.1.1&x=384&y=160

Comment: @pavlos that might be useful for debugging but overriding the url returned by OpenLayers is unlikely to be a practical long term option

Comment: does a GetCapabilities request show yyy:boundaryline as being queryable?

`<Layer queryable="1">
<Name>yyy:boundaryline</Name>`

Comment: @Mike I just want to make sure somehow it works. Next thing is to check the geosever log and find the error.

Comment: As the url is being generated by OpenLayers and there are clearly some problems with it (e.g. version specified twice) can you also show the code and options you have used to generated the TileWMS source and the getGetFeatureInfoUrl() call?

Comment: As CRS not SRS is used, we can say this should be a WMS version 1.3.0 GFI request, so what your constructed URL should look like is:   `https://geoserver.xxx.com/geoserver/yyy/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=yyy%3Aboundaryline&tiled=true&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&I=219&J=208&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES&BBOX=-508764.86026613414%2C6966165.009797823%2C-469629.1017841239%2C7005300.768279833&query_layers=layers=yyy%3Aboundaryline&`

Comment: If OpenLayers docs say: If QUERY_LAYERS is not provided then the layers specified in the LAYERS parameter will be used. I would take that to mean that, OpenLayers will generate a request that will specify the layer or layers in the LAYERS parameter, in the QUERY_LAYERS parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with that URL.

1. Two versions specified: You can't use version=1.3 and version=1.1.1 in the same request as the format of the request changed between those versions (X,Y vs I,J).
2. Missing `QUERY_LAYERS`: If you look at the [GeoServer documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) you will see that `QUERY_LAYERS` is a required parameter (it can be a subset or all of `LAYERS` as required).
3. `INFO_FORMAT=application/json`: If you want GML output then you will need to set `INFO_FORMAT=application/vnd.ogc.gml`.

Comment: QUERY_LAYERS doesn't have to be a list of any of any of layers from the GetMap request, just available in the service.

Comment: I think geoserver at least will not find a feature that has not been drawn on the map.